# How to install Proc::Daemon module

Tags: linux, perl, error-handling, daemon, texas-instruments

I have just bought SensorTag CC3200STK. I want to read it's data through Raspberry Pi. I searched a lot but could not find any way to read it's data. Finally I found a code and the author told me to just run the code. I think this guy is trying to run a Perl code as a daemon. When I run the code I get the following Error.

```
Can't locate Proc/Daemon.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Proc::Daemon module) 
(@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./wifisensortagd line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./wifisensortagd line 8.
```

I have attached the code as a jsfiddle (I know it is not a js code).
https://jsfiddle.net/9eLkn6of/

How should I resolve this Error? 
P.S : The .cfg file included in the code contains

```
Sensors: "192.168.1.1","192.168.1.1"
Locations: "Work Room","Living Room"
Site: Hassan Home
Mqttserver: pi3.garf.de
```

Comment: You will need to install the Proc::Daemon module ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Daemon ). If you are using a Debian-like Linux distribution, the likely easiest approach is `apt-get install libproc-daemon-perl` . The installation of Proc::Daemon is not different from installing any other Perl module.

Comment: I installed it. Now I am getting error of installing Config :simple module

Comment: ... then repeat the same process, this time for the `Config::Simple` module, which can be likely found as package `libconfig-simple-perl` on Debian-like systems. You will have to do this for likely every `use ...` line in the script you're trying to use. You should investigate of that script is already packaged somewhere with all prerequisites.

Comment: ... the original source seems to be https://github.com/wtremmel/wifi-sensortag , and that author does not list their prerequisites unfortunately.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thank You for your help. Although his code did not work :(

Answer (score 2):

@Corion comments were really helpful. I resolved the error by installing these two modules.

```
sudo apt-get install libproc-daemon-perl
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libconfig-simple-perl
```